# Understanding Data Binding for Windows Phone 7

Tags: architecture, windows-phone-7

I want to develop a simple app for the Windows Phone 7 platform. It's basically a vocabulary based game that involves the user moving word tiles from one area to another to score points.

I want to know what is the best way of tying the UI to the game's backend? I saw the Windows Phone 7 jumpstart videos, there they touch up on Data Binding but don't really go into any depth.

I'm a newbie and don't have any experience with designing the architecture for a phone app,
It'd be great if someone could explain what steps I should be taking or guide me to a resource from where I could learn more.

Comment: did you check resources suggested in **[windows-phone-7 tag wiki at Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-phone-7/info)**? "Windows Phone 7 Development for Absolute Beginners" etc...

Comment: Yes, i have familiarized myself with the Basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This month's issue of MSDN magazine has a good article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852595.aspx.

However, when you used the phrase "tying the UI to the game's backend" and the word "architecture", I'm thinking that you need more information beyond simply binding from a XAML view to an object behind it. I'm thinking you should start reading about MVVM, as well as general WP7 architecture guidance.

There's stuff all over the web but the problem is that the overall guidance is not fully prescriptive in all cases - MS has advice for you, but no silver bullet. This makes it hard to pull any useful information out of all the noise on message boards and places like StackOverflow (not implying that there aren't good answers out there, but you will find many that are conflicting, overly confusing or tailored to specific scenarios.)

In my opinion, the best way to get started is with the publications from [MS Patterns and Practices.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/bb190351) Hit that link and Ctrl-F for "phone" and get to reading. Even the "retired" Windows Phone 7 Developer Guide there is great, but I'd start at the top with the Phone/MVVM one. Check out the Resources in that one, including Karl's "MVVM In the Box". And *make sure* you actually download and study the code as well as reading the article.

Comment: You're right that looks promising, I'll try that code now.

Answer (score 2):

If you think you already know the basics and still need guidance, I suggest you get a good book on the subject. For example, Charles Petzold offers a free e-book on Windows Phone 7 that can be downloaded [here](http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone).